# Downloading a Raw Acces log file from CPanel

Tags: python, cpanel

I'm trying to download the Raw Acces Logs (a file with the extension .gz) from CPanel using Python, here is the script I am using:

```
import requests
CREDENTIALS = {'username': 'someuser', 'password': 'somepass'}

url = 'https://site/getlogarchive/logname.gz'

resp = requests.get(url, data=CREDENTIALS, allow_redirects=True, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}, stream=True)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    filename ='somepathhere\\log.txt'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
    print("done")
else:
    print("not done")
```

I have a problem with this though, the `log.txt` file won't contain the data from the archive and instead it will contain the HTML of the CPanel page.

I tried entering the url from another browser where I was not logged in, and when you enter it shows you the log in page (That's why the `.get` has `data=CREDENTIALS`). If you successfully log in, it will download the file automatically in, so I have no idea why this code doesn't work.

The only problems I could think of are the redirect of the page or the way I handle the content.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I found the answer to my problem!
Here is the code that works for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://site/getlogarchive/logname.gz'

resp = requests.get(url, auth=('someuser', 'somepass'), allow_redirects=True, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}, stream=True)
if resp.status_code == 200:
    filename ='log.gz'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
```

This way the file is saved as a .gz file that I can later read as I want.